# How to make use of BleNordicUART with Movesense

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, movesense

I want to make use of BLE UART (BleNordicUART module) with my custom firmware for printing simple debug outputs (I don't have a programming jig). 
I didn't find any information regarding BLE UART in the wiki or sources.
I can find and connect to the BLE UART service from my Android device, but no data is received.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to using the BLE Nordic UART is the *DebugService* which can provide you with live debug messages as well as store them to EEPROM for later retrieval.

The documentation on that is still a bit sparse (see: *debug.yaml* in MovesenseCoreLib) but here's the short version:

To write (info level) debug message in the code (see: DebugLogger.hpp for other levels):

```
DebugLogger::info("stateChange DOUBLETAP: newState = %d", stateChange.newState);
```

To get DebugMessages over BLE:

- Subscribe to path */System/Debug/{Level}* where {Level} is one of:

  - 'Fatal': 0
  - 'Error': 1
  - 'Warning': 2
  - 'Info': 3
  - 'Verbose': 4

To store the debug messages to EEPROM you must define the memory area to use in 
*App.cpp* and make sure it does not overlap with Logbook memory. Example of definition (16kB for debug, rest for logbook):

```
// Define 16kB DEBUG message area
// NOTE: If building a simulator build, these macros are obligatory!
DEBUGSERVICE_BUFFER_SIZE(6, 120); // 6 lines, 120 characters total
DEBUG_EEPROM_MEMORY_AREA(true, 0, 16384)
// Rest of the EEPROM is for Logbook 
LOGBOOK_MEMORY_AREA(16384, (384 * 1024)-16384);
```

...and configure the minimum level to store to EEPROM with PUT on */System/Debug/Log/Config*.

To fetch entries from EEPROM, do GET on */System/Debug/Log* with query object that contains the max timestamp ( in Movesense >=1.9 use "Id") to fetch (the GET returns max 4-6 entries at the time so you have to call it repeatedly to get all the entries).

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Answer (score 0):

Found the send_ble_nus_data() function in BleController.hpp.